# Finding the volume of a solid via triple integrals and spherical coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration

Let S be the Solid enclosed above by $x^2+y^2+z^2=2$, below by $x^2+y^2=z^2$ and y=0. Use triple integrals and spherical coordinates to evaluate the volume of the solid S.(I just need to know what the iterated integrals are, once iterated integrals are known, i would be able to solve the question.)

My try

Since $x^2+y^2+z^2=2$ that would mean $p^2=2$ and hence $p=\sqrt{2}$.

The bound for $p$ will be $0<p<\sqrt{2}$.

While the bound for $\theta $ will be $0<\theta <2\pi$

This is the part im unsure of

What i got was $0< \phi<\pi/4$

I got $\phi$ by converting the equation $x^2+y^2+z^2=2$ into spherical coordinates and

after simplifying the expression, i got $tan\phi=1$ which then gives the range of $0< \phi<\pi/4$

Im unsure whether my answers are correct. Could anyone explain. Thanks

Comment: Draw a picture and use common sense.  The solid is symmetric about the $z$ axis.

Comment: I would say if y = 0 then count only half of the solid.

Comment: Do not forget the Jacobian.

Comment: $x^2+y^2=z^2$ is a vertical cylinder. Can't enclose below (nor above). Ditto for $y=0$. Can be $z=0$?

Comment: Could u please help me with this Vector Calculus question as well. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1032364/finding-the-circulation-of-a-curve-in-a-solid-vector-calculus Thanks