# Finding the Circulation of a Curve in a Solid. (Vector Calculus)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals, surface-integrals

A solid can in spherical coordinates 
\begin{equation}
x=\rho\sin\phi\cos\theta\\
y=\rho\sin\phi\sin\theta\\
z=\rho\cos\phi
\end{equation}

be described by the following inequalities
             $$0<\rho<1-\cos\phi$$

Let a curve $C$ be the intersection of the boundary surface of the solid with the plane $y=0$ and equip $C$ with an anticlockwise orientation as seen from the positive $y-axis$. Find the circulation

$$\int_{C}(z+e^x)\:dx+e^{x^3+z^3}\:dy+(\sin y-x)\:dz$$

What i tried

The solid is clearly a sphere.
Using Stokes theorem i took the curl of the following vector field and i got $$\nabla\times F=(\cos y-3z^2e^{x^3+z^3},2,3x^2e^{x^3+z^3})$$

The normal $n=(0,1,0)$ since the curve lies on the $xz$ plane as $y=0$

Then i took the dot product of $\nabla\times F$ and $n$ to get a value of $2$, which means to say the integral is $2$ times the area of $C$ when projected in the $xz$ plane. Im unsure about my workings though. Could anyone please help me with this. Thanks

Comment: The solid is not a sphere. It's rotation symmetric to the $z$-axis. It's "boundary" can be obtained by rotating the curve $\rho = 1-\cos\phi$ around the $z$-axis. Actually, that's not entirely correct. You will see what I mean if you look at the curve $\rho = 1-\cos\phi$. To see the curve, enter "polar plot r=1-cos theta" without the quotes at Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: I know, it shaped like an apple but im still having problems getting the integral of the curve C. Could u Please help me with this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parametrization of the surface:
$$
\eqalign{
x&=\rho\sin\phi\cr
y&=0\cr
z&=\rho\cos\phi
}$$
$$0\le\phi\le\pi,\qquad 0\le\rho\le 1-\cos\phi$$
union
$$
\eqalign{
x&=-\rho\sin\phi\cr
y&=0\cr
z&=\rho\cos\phi
}$$
$$0\le\phi\le\pi,\qquad 0\le\rho\le 1-\cos\phi$$

Normal vector in the first chunk:
$$N=(\sin\phi,0,\cos\phi)\times(\rho\cos\phi,0,-\rho\sin\phi)=(0,\rho,0)$$

Normal vector in the second chunk: the same.

Parametrization of the curve:
$$
\eqalign{
x&=(1-\cos\phi)\sin\phi\cr
y&=0\cr
z&=(1-\cos\phi)\cos\phi
}$$
$$0\le\phi\le\pi$$
union
$$
\eqalign{
x&=(\cos\phi-1)\sin\phi\cr
y&=0\cr
z&=(1-\cos\phi)\cos\phi
}$$
$$0\le\phi\le\pi$$
**Warning**: with this parametrization the orientation of the curve is reversed in the first chunk.

Comment: How did u get the range for $\rho$

Comment: @yswong, from $0<\rho<1−\cos\phi$ plus the obvious symmetry.

Comment: @yswong, edit with important correction

Comment: I got $N=(0,1,0)$. Is it correct?

Comment: @yswong, $N$ depends of the parametrization.

Comment: Oh i see. Yeah Thanks for the answwr

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18924/discussion-between-ys-wong-and-martin-blas-perez-pinilla).

Comment: @yswong, I think that this is the good.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use spherical coordinates up until the surface integral. What you've done seems correct to me now all is left is to calculate the area which can be done in spherical coordinates since the limits of integration are given to you