# limits of integration in spherical coordinates.

Tags: integration, volume

Consider a cone centered about the positive z axis with its vertex at origin,a $90^{\circ}$ angle at its vertex,topped by a sphere of radius $6$.Compute the volume of region bounded by sphere and cone.

My problem:I  need help about the limits of integration in spherical coordinates.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to specify the center of the sphere. Is it at the origin?

Comment: It is not specified in the question.

Comment: There is not enough information to solve it if the sphere is centered at an arbitrary unknown point, so it is safe to assume that they intend the sphere to be centered at the origin as well.

Comment: Hmmm..."topped by" is slightly ambiguous. One possibility is that the sphere is like a ball dropped down a conical funnel and resting at a place where the cone's cross-sectional radius is also 6.

Comment: SO if we suppose that its center is origin then what should be the limits.

Comment: I added the limits in spherical as well.

Comment: @user_of_math thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A picture always helps.  The green region is the one you are interested in (assuming sphere centered at origin)

[image: sphere and cone]

The limits of integration for spherical coordinates as you rightly noted in comments in the other post are $0\leq r \leq 6$ and $0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi$

For finding the limits for $\phi$, refer to the picture and note that the problem specified that the angle of the black triangle at the vertex is $90^\circ = \pi/2$.  Consider how much of an angle from the red line you will need to go down (hint: the red line bisects the angle) to find the largest $\phi$ can be.

Comment: I think then $-\pi/4\leq \phi \leq \pi/4$.Is this correct?

Comment: $\phi$ will range in some subset of $[0,\pi]$.  An angle of $-\pi/4$ is exactly the same as an angle of $\pi/4$, just on the other side.  The fact that $\theta$ spins it around takes care of covering that already.  You are very close though.  It will in fact be $0\leq \phi \leq \pi/4$

Comment: Yes it should be in $[0,\pi]$.Thank you very much.

Comment: Could u help me with this vector calculus question as well. I really need help for this. Thanks. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1032364/finding-the-circulation-of-a-curve-in-a-solid-vector-calculus

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to determine the limits. Given the cone's angle, its equation is $x^2+y^2=z^2$. assuming the sphere is centered at the origin, its equation is $x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2$, with $R=6$

In cone-sphere problems, remember that the cone extends forever, but the sphere is bounded. On the other hand, the cone starts as a point. If you take z-slices of the volume,
it starts off as a single point (the apex of the cone), but widens thereon.

The slices are essentially circles $x^2+y^2=z^2$ for a fixed 'z'. However, beyond $z=3\sqrt{2}$, the slice at which the cone intersects the sphere, the outer limit is determined by the sphere. They are still bounded by circles, but of radius $\sqrt{R^2-z^2}$.

This should be enough information for you to find the limits.

Edited to add: If you work through, your integral will split into two integrals.

$$
\int_{z=0}^{3\sqrt{2}} \int_{r=0}^{z} \int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi} r d\theta dr dz +
\int_{z=3\sqrt{2}}^{6} \int_{r=0}^{\sqrt{6^2-z^2}} \int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi} r d\theta dr dz 
$$

ETA2: In spherical,

$$
\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi} \int_{\phi=0}^{\pi/4} \int_{r=0}^{6} r^2 \sin\phi dr d\phi d\theta
$$

Comment: In spherical coordinates $0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi$ and $0\leq r\leq 6$.Are these correct?

Comment: I am still unable to find the limits for $\phi$

Comment: this answer currently uses cylindrical coordinates, however life will be much simpler to use spherical coordinates

Comment: @JMoravitz I need spherical coordinates.

Comment: @user_of_math I highly disagree with that statement.  The coordinate system used should be chosen to make the limits of integration easiest in every case, and for spherical coordinates the limits are all from constants to constants instead of depending on a variable in a limit of integration.

Comment: @JMoravitz Actually, you're right. It is easier in spherical.

Comment: In most texts, $\theta$ refers to the angle on the $x-y$ plane, and $\phi$ refers to the angle away from the $z$ axis.  The variable names used in this answer are flipped from what most people would expect which would make the Jacobian incorrect in this case.  If you had flipped the names of variables, it should be $r^2 \sin \theta$ if you defined it in the opposite manner.

Comment: @JMoravitz I have seen $\theta$ used as the co-latitude more often than not.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html  Even if you prefer to use $\theta$ as the co-latitude instead, the Jacobian would need to reflect that.  Furthermore, it is best to match notations to the question asker.  He had earlier written he expected $0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi$ which only makes sense if $\theta$ is the polar angle.

Comment: @JMoravitz Of course - thanks for the edit. Gotta be more careful with spherical coordinates!